# Disable Security in function

Tags: security, cakephp

I get a image in POST, my ​​idea is to disable security within this function.

Is it possible? Any Idea?

```
public function admin_addImage($id = null){
    $this->Hotel->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Hotel->exists())
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Hotel'));
    $image = $_FILES['uploadImage'];
    ClassRegistry::init('HotelImage')->create();
    if ($image['name']) {
        $imageName = md5(Security::generateAuthKey());
        $result = $this->uploadFiles('files/hotels/images', array($image), $imageName, null, 'I',array('width' => 300, 'height' => 300));
        if (!empty($result['errors'][0])) {
            $this->Session->setError(__('Invalid file format'));
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }
        if($result['urls'][0]){
            ClassRegistry::init('HotelImage')->save(array('hotel_id'=>$id));
            ClassRegistry::init('HotelImage')->saveField('image', md5($imageName).'.'.basicsLix::getExtension($image['name']));
        }
    } 
$this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

Solution :

```
if(isset($this->Security) && $this->RequestHandler->isPost() && $this->action == 'admin_addImage'){
            $this->Security->validatePost = false;
            $this->Security->enabled = false;
            $this->Security->csrfCheck = false;
    }
```

Comment: Disable what security?

Comment: this security : public  $components = array('Security','Acl', 'RequestHandler')

Comment: Why do you need / want to disable it at all?

Comment: Because send me error "blackhole" for using the POST method, Anyway I already resolved and leave here the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is specifically answered in the book:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#disabling-security-component-for-specific-actions

> There may be cases where you want to disable all security checks for
>   an action (ex. AJAX requests). You may “unlock” these actions by
>   listing them in $this->Security->unlockedActions in your beforeFilter.